# Calculator App crushed when push value on Stack

Tags: java, android, calculator

I want to make a Stack Calculator App. 
When i entered a value and press Enter( then a value should be pushed on the stack) my App chrushed with following exception:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.admin.calculator.Caluculator.calculate()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.admin.calculator.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:66)
(that's the line with case R.id.button17...)

My MainActivity class :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener {


public  EditText TextField;
Calculator c = new Calculator();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button b1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); 
    b1.setOnClickListener(this);
    ... some Buttons

    TextField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
   }

public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:  TextField.append("7");  break;
        ... some buttons            
        case R.id.button17: c.calculate(); TextField.setText("");break // Enter Button
        case R.id.button18: TextField.setText("");   break; // Clear Button

    }
}

  public static String getTextfromTextField() {
    return TextField.getText().toString();
 }

}
```

And my Calculator class:

```
public class Calculator { // RechenLogik
MainActivity activity; // MainActivity Instance
EditText TextField;
Stack<Double> stack = new Stack<Double>();

public Calculator(MainActivity activity ) {
    this.activity = activity;
}


public void calculate() {
    String input = activity.getTextfromTextField();
    double value;

      try {
        value = Double.parseDouble(input);
        stack.push(zahl);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        if (input.equals("+") ||
            input.equals("-")) {
               ...   some other signs                 
        } 
     }            

      if(input.equals("+")) {
        double value1=stack.pop();
        double value2=stack.pop();
        stack.push(value1+value2);
        value2=value1+value2;
        stack.push(value2);
        String tmp = Double.toString(value2);
        activity.setTextFeldText(value2);
    }
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: i think NPE should be through on line String input = activity.getTextfromTextField();   because you activity is uninitialized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to call calculator constructor `Calculator ()` like this:

```
Calculator c = new Calculator(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try putting some log outputs in the Calculate method and before the switch on click. Checking that that id definitely exists and checking that 'String input' is getting a value.

Log.v("Tag", "Message");

Comment: When i write Log.v("Tag", "Message"); i got error cannot resolve symbol 'Log'

Comment: Make sure you've imported Log, 
import android.util.Log;

Answer (score 0):

Could you add

```
Calculator c = new calculator (this);
```

inside the onClick method.

You have a constructor on the calculator class that expects an activity object.

Comment: Thanks, now my App don't crushed anymore.